# Spring-Data-Jpa - Empty a table with foreign key on itself

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to empty a table which has a foreign key on itself ?

I would like to delete all rows from table but this table as a field which reference the primary key of the same table (which define parent-children rows).

I think I have to delete first all the children, and then all the parent, but how can I do that with Spring-Data-Jpa ?

What I have done is

```
@Query("DELETE FROM article a WHERE a.geniusClientId = :geniusClientId")
```

...but I get violations constraint exceptions in some cases.

The db I use is MariaDB.

Here is an extract of my entity :

```
@Entity(name = "article")
public class Article extends AbstractSynchronizable implements Serializable {

    public static final String COLOR_VARIANT_REFERENCE = "color";
    public static final String SIZE_VARIANT_REFERENCE = "size";

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Image> images;
    private String label;
    private long vatInclusivePrice;
    private long vatExclusivePrice;
    private long taxRate;
    private long supplierVatInclusivePrice;
    private long supplierVatExclusivePrice;
    private long supplierTaxRate;
    private long oldPrice;
    private long stock;
    private String reference;
    private String description;
    private String barcode;
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Article parent;

    ...
 }
```

Comment: what about this annotation `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE`, or `@OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true)`

Comment: can you please show us your entity?

Comment: I added the entity

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just an annotation in your entity :

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Article parent;
```

Or :

```
@ManyToOne(orphanRemoval=true)
private Article parent;
```

take a look at :

- [Cascading Remove](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Cascading_Remove_)
- [Orphan Removal](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_)

Comment: That is not working because the problem of putting the cascade on the field named "parent" means: "delete the parent when removing the child".
But when I do a deleteAll, I want to do the opposite: I am removing the parent, and I want to remove the child as well.

Comment: @psv what if the child had child, and child had child, ..., you want to remove all them?

Comment: Yes -----------

Comment: @psv I think there are something weird in your conception, If we consider that the Article have a parent, then It should strongly have list of children, but i don't see this in your entity, I think you need `List<Article> childrenList;` in your entity, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: According to me, there are two solutions: either you have a single parent or you have a list of children. It depends how you think the conception. I chose to have a parent Article, but in this case I should not add the list of children because it may cause cyclic dependencies. But in my case you're probably right: a list of children would be simple when I want to remove the parent.

Comment: Exactly @psv, remove the parrent and use list, and I think you have to use `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) private List<Article> children;`

Comment: Sorry for the late check, I don't see your answer until now, what problem you mean @user, I think ESala already solve your problem no :)

Comment: Yes, he solved my problem. I asked you before ESala commented my question. Thanks!